# HTML Sort - Header on different table

Tags: html

I have the below html table where the header on seperate table and content on another table. I have to sort the table when i click the header that are in another table.

I found so many javascript examples that are working only if the headers are in same table.Can any you guys give me with some examples related to my task?

```
<html> 
    <table > 
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr> 
    </table> 
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Fred</td>
            <td>$12000.00</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>Kevin</td>
            <td>$191200.00</td>
        </tr> 
    </table>
</html>
```

Comment: My Html Table:
<html>
<table >
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Salary</th></tr>
 </table> 
 <table>
  <tr><td>Fred</td><td>$12000.00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Kevin</td><td>$191200.00</td></tr>
</table>
</html>

Comment: get an example going at jsfiddle.net, apply your favorite js method that didn't work. Save it and post the link back here. The bigger the starting point you provide, the easier it is to help you, and therefore the more likely you will get help.

Comment: Why are these things in separate tables? Redo the markup so that there's one table with two columns and three rows.

Comment: @JackManey - I think if the OP could do that, he'd've gone with the "many javascript examples" that he found while doing research. We should assume that his requirements are for the headings and the data to be in separate tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you add some classes to the columns so that the column cells and the associated header have the same class name, it's not too difficult to leverage those other existing JavaScript solutions.

As an example, I used this [simple JQuery sorting function](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/) and created [this JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EumEe/2/).

I modified the HTML like this:

```
<html> 
    <table id="heading"> 
        <tr>
            <th class="name-col">Name</th>
            <th class="salary-col">Salary</th>
        </tr> 
    </table> 
    <table id="data">
        <tr>
            <td class="name-col">Fred</td>
            <td class="salary-col">$12000.00</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td class="name-col">Kevin</td>
            <td class="salary-col">$191200.00</td>
        </tr> 
    </table>
</html>​
```

Notice that I game the header Name and all of the cells in that column the class `name-col`, and I did the same for the Salary header and cells with the class `salary-col`.

Then I used JQuery to add a click listener to the `name-col` *header*, which then triggered the sort function on the `name-col` *cells*:

```
$('th.name-col').click(function() {
    $('td.name-col').sortElements(function(a, b){
        return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1;
    }, function(){ return this.parentNode; });
});

$('th.salary-col').click(function() {
    $('td.salary-col').sortElements(function(a, b){
        return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1;
    }, function(){ return this.parentNode; });
});
```

In this example, `sortElements` is the function provided in the simple JQuery sorting function I linked above. I am not the author of it.

You will notice that this script will only sort once, however, since the direction of the comparator (`>`) is hard-coded. One quick-n-dirty way to implement logic to reverse this sort is like this:

```
var nameAsc = false;
var salaryAsc = false;

$('th.name-col').click(function() {
    $('td.name-col').sortElements(function(a, b){
        if (nameAsc) {
            nameAsc = false;
            return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1;
        } else {
            nameAsc = true;
            return $(a).text() < $(b).text() ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }, function(){ return this.parentNode; });
});

$('th.salary-col').click(function() {
    $('td.salary-col').sortElements(function(a, b){
        if(salaryAsc) {
            salaryAsc = false;
            return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1;
        } else {
            salaryAsc = true;
            return $(a).text() < $(b).text() ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }, function(){ return this.parentNode; });
});
```

Here the `nameAsc` and `salaryAsc` boolean variables are just a hackish way of allowing you to reverse the sort order. If it's ascending, it flips the boolean and the direction of the `>` in the comparator function. There's probably a more efficient way to do this, but I was just going for a quick-and-dirty example.

You're going to have a lot of problems with your two-table model, especially with sizing the columns. If you have longer data in the cells in the data table, your data columns will no longer line up with your header columns. I strongly suggest you use just a single table for both the header *and* the data.

Comment: First ,thank you very  much for your time on this.I tried your above example.I understood the concept of sorting.I think the above sort example is for a table that have 2 rows . right? 
My table have more rows. Can I able to pass all the rows using array? I don't know how to pass the  array function...Can you help with this??
also ,I am not facing any UI issues with the header.It is lining up properly.

Comment: @user1397157 - The above is not actually production code, it's a proof of concept that you can take *any* of the pre-existing sort-table functions and adapt them by triggering the sort action on a click event on a different table. I'm sure you could adapt the above if you'd like, but as I said, it's a quick-n-dirty example, not something intended for actual use.

Comment: Not a particularly big thank you for all the effort you put in writing all this up, no upvotes or accepted. +1 from me, @user1397157 is obvs a help vampire

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, and your a climber! I'd give you +2 if I could :D One day I'll make it to the rockies.

Answer (score 0):

use sorttable.js for sorting, it might give problem with column alignment while clicking on column head for sorting....

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://community.wikidot.com/local--files/howto:sortable-tables-js/sorttable.js"></script>

<style>
        th, td{
            padding: 3px;//important
        }
</style>
<table class="sortable">
<tr><th>...</th></tr><tr><td>...</td</tr>
</table>
```